# Getting empty sequence for the complex type in generated XSD when developing JAX-WS web services

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, xsd, wsdl

I seem to be having an issue with Java and NetBeans when it comes to writing web services.
I have searched for a couple of days with no luck, finding people with the same issue as me with zero replies.

I have created a web service which returns a complex type (LoginReply), and that complex type contains an array of another complex type (AppInfo)

However when I generate the WSDL from this, the complex type definition in the XSD is blank, and manually adding the information still makes the web service return null even when data is successfully passed to the web service.

```
<xs:complexType name="appInfo">
<xs:sequence/>
</xs:complexType>
```

LoginReply: http://pastebin.com/Umx6ayvi
AppInfo: http://pastebin.com/566WnZ4H

If anyone could point out what I'm doing wrong, or if this is a bug with NetBeans, I'm new to Java so I can't rule out that I'm simply not understanding something, but I'm close to pulling my hair out here.

EDIT:

Just noticed when i deploy to tomcat via NetBeans I get the following error:

```
WARNING: duplicate class definition bug occured? Please report this :    uk/co/example/ComplexTypes/LoginReply$JaxbAccessorM_getApplications_setApplications_[Luk_co_example_ComplexTypes_AppInfo;

java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal class name "uk/co/example/ComplexTypes/LoginReply$JaxbAccessorM_getApplications_setApplications_[Luk_co_example_ComplexTypes_AppInfo;" in class file uk/co/example/ComplexTypes/LoginReply$JaxbAccessorM_getApplications_setApplications_[Luk_co_example_ComplexTypes_AppInfo;
```

Notice the random L before co_uk_example. My research suggests this is an old bug that should be fixed, and that no one else has reported this issue in over a year, no sure where to go from here.

Another edit:

Just added a new web method on the service that simply gets a list of appInfo and returns it to the client. This still fails the same way with NetBeans refusing to generate a sequence inside AppInfo. 
I'm sure I'm missing something to declare the class, but I have checked it countless times to ensure I'm not missing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Issue came down to a very simple mistake. The AppInfo class was using non-standard getters and setters.

```
public void SetAppID(int AppID)
{
    this.AppID = AppID;
}
```

This is INCORRECT (notice the capital on the Set), it should be:

```
public void setAppID(int AppID)
{
    this.AppID = AppID;
}
```

Using a capital is not standard for JavaBeans and as such JAX-WS didn't know how to generate WSDL for this class. Thanks too shyam from the following link for answering the question

[How to return a custom complex type in JAX-WS web services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955313/netbeans-jax-ws-return-custom-complex-type-n/12955488#12955488)

Answer (score 1):

warning gives you good hint: "WARNING: duplicate class definition bug occured"

- your ws implementation class directly uses LoginReply class which directly uses AppInfo (+you are maybe also directly using this class in your ws implementation) => jaxb finds it

  @XMLSeeAlso(...) tells jaxb to "link" referenced class

=> two definitions of the same class (not sure if it is by design or a bug that jaxb is not able to handle this case more gracefully)

to fix this just remove @XmlSeeAlso from your LoginReply class and you should be fine

Comment: Thanks for your reply and suggestion however


That warning was present before i added @XmlSeeAlso. that was an attempt to solve the issue with the empty xs:sequence in AppInfo. Which it didnt. for some reason, jaxb will not recognize the contents of Appinfo. I have attempted to re-write that class to end with the same issue. 

I'm not sure if i need to add something extra to the class, but LoginReply generates correctly without anything additional.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can send "complex types" over the net (programmed port types) in http protocol, however an array may be implicitly converted to a delimited string set  , check the docs for data transfer.

Comment: Im not entirely sure what your talking about here, complextypes are designed to be sent via the web service :/